# Dir all C: except Windows folder

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm trying to do a DIR that show me all folders and sub-folders except Windows folder.

Comment: This sort of question belongs on SuperUser, not here, because it's computer-related but not programming-related.

Answer (score 3):

Do a directory listing with `s`ubfolders and `a`ttribute is `d`irectory on drive `C:\`

```
dir /s /ad "C:\" | findstr /v "\Windows"
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you want to omit "C:\Windows" and all subdirectories under it.

```
DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\" | FINDSTR /B /V "C:\Windows"
```

Comment: And its possible to show the size of the files?

Comment: @K1c09_Dev - The question says that you want to see directories.